# Increment number & Rename multiple files with #1.png

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, file-io

environment: Visual Studio 2019, Windows Forms Application, C#

Hi! I would like to rename (batch) some files with #1, #2, #3 etc. I have folders like 1-file, 2-file and inside each folder i have around around 50 000 file with names: abc.png, def.png, ghi.png I want: abc#1.png, def#2.png, ghi#3.png

Something similar...

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDlg.ShowDialog();

string[] pngFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath, "*.png");
string[] newFileName = new string[pngFiles.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < pngFiles .Length; i++)
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pngFiles [i]);
    string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pngFiles[i]);

    newFileName = pngFiles [i];

    File.Move(pngFiles [i], filePath + "\\" + newFileName[1] + 1 + fileExt);`
}
```

But this code doesn't work. Error here...

> Exception was originally thrown at this call stack:     [External Code]     NFT.Form1.button1_Click.AnonymousMethod__1_1(<>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>) in Form1.cs     [External Code]     NFT.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs     [External Code]     NFT.Program.Main() in Program.cs

Also, I am not sure i can implement the increase counter and include that number to the file preceding #

Please let me know

Comment: Most people read the exception message... We do too

Comment: yes, i get this This `exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    NFT.Form1.button1_Click.AnonymousMethod__1_1(<>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>) in Form1.cs
    [External Code]
    NFT.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
    [External Code]
    NFT.Program.Main() in Program.cs`

Comment: `newFileName` is likely going to be wrong. it will be the the full path, you are going to need `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` at some point

Comment: can you submit a solution, please

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: `newFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pngFiles[i])` would be one issues

Comment: Next time please post the complete exception which consists of the exception name, message and call stack. And don't add such crucial information as comment. Instead edit your question.

Comment: Winforms is not WPF. Use proper tags.

Comment: hey @BionicCode so amazing,, it worked :) the only thing is its not looking the subfolders, i want to do that as well. Is there a way. I have so many subfolder inside so i want to look insider every folder and look for .png files and rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to improve the performance: when you use `Directory.GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array, whereas `Directory.EnumerateFiles` will return file by file.

Also use string interpolation and `FileSystem.RenameFile` to gracefully rename the file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
  folderDlg.ShowDialog();
  if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
  {
    return;
  }

  // Has different framework dependend implementations 
  // in order to handle unauthorized access to subfolders
  RenamePngFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
}
```

### .NET Core/.NET

```
private void RenamePngFiles(string directoryPath)
{
  int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
  foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png", new EnumerationOptions()))
  {
    // The new file name without path
    var newFileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName)}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";

    FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
  }
}
```

### .NET Framework

```
private void RenamePngFiles(string directoryPath)
{
  int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
  foreach (string originalFullFileName in EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
  {
    // The new file name without path
    var newFileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName)}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";

    FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
  }
}

private IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(
  string directoryPath, 
  string searchPattern, 
  SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
{
  IEnumerable<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
  try
  {
    filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, searchPattern);
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
  {
    yield break;
  }

  foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
  {
    yield return filePath;
  }

  if (searchOption.Equals(SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
  {
    yield break;
  }

  foreach (string subdirectoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directoryPath))
  {
    foreach (string filePath in EnumerateFiles(subdirectoryPath, searchPattern))
    {
      yield return filePath;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, when i used i got three below errors. `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'EnumerationOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'newFileName' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the current context 1

Comment: below is the link to pastebin code: https://pastebin.com/A4yLu0in

Comment: Don't use your original code. Use mine. Only add the create and show dialog part (two lines).

Comment: Which framework do you use, .NET 5? It seems you are using the old .NET Framework 4.x? The EnumerateFiles overload used in the example is not available in .NET Framework. Only since .NET Core. If you are not using .NET Core/.NET 5 then I can modify the example to use a different overload.

Comment: Please read carefully. The answer was meant to replace your failing code with an improved version. I have updated the example so that you can copy&paste the code in zombie mode. Also the code now uses the .NET Framework Directory.EnumerateFiles API.

Comment: I am using .NEt framework 4.7.2

Comment: hey @BionicCode so amazing,, it worked :) the only thing is its not looking the subfolders, i want to do that as well. Is there a way. I have so many subfolder inside so i want to look insider every folder and look for .png files and rename it

Comment: I have updated the solution to allow recursion.

Comment: So i updated the codes but i get below error: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0104 'SearchOption' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption' and 'System.IO.SearchOption`
`

Comment: when i tried the .Net Core/.Net function then i get below error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Management.EnumerationOptions' to 'System.IO.SearchOption'`

Comment: You are using the wrong types i.e. you use the wrong namespace. The examples use the `System.IO`  namespace: `System.IO.SearchOptions` and `System.IO.EnumerationOptions`. You erroneously use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption` and  `'System.Management.EnumerationOptions`. Use `System.IO`.

Comment: You should add `using System.IO;` to the code file's using declarations.

Comment: Yes, i tried all three differnt namespace and i was geting error. See my codes in pastebin. https://pastebin.com/H8gNJgU4  . I get error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'EnumerationOptions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: i tried the edited one but i am getting below error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Management.EnumerationOptions' to 'System.IO.SearchOption' `

Comment: Again, you are using the wrong namespace! Read the error message it says 'System.Management.EnumerationOptions'. But it must be 'System.IO.EnumerationOptions'. Furthermore, if you want to use the .NET Core/.NET version make sure your project is targeting .NET Core or .NET 5. The EnumerationOptions version is not available for .NET Framework 4.x. That's why I've added a framework version header to both solutions!!! Because you use  .NET Framework 4.7.2  you must use the longer .NET Framework solution.